# Odoo hide field with attrs

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

If fields (user_id or car_id or city_id) = FALSE (Empty field) I need hide field time_id

Below example work for one field how add other field here?

```
attrs="{'invisible': [('user_id', '=', False)]}"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```xml
<field name="time_id" attrs="{'invisible': ['|', '|', ('user_id', '=', False), ('car_id', '=', False), ('city_id', '=', False)]}"/>
```

Comment: Naglis you edited a lot of my answer but do you make an up vote when you see it's correct answer like i did now